# unable to fix liqibase maven plugin update sql during the process of building war file for mifos source code?

Tags: java, maven-plugin, maven-3, maven-assembly-plugin, maven-release-plugin

error during building war file.we r building war file for mifos source code through maven tool. mifos is java open source code. we use mvn clean package -Dmaven.test.skip=ture cmd and give path name til head folder of source code as shown below

```
C:\mifos_src_code\mifos-head-2.1.6-0-gb6f7b86\mifos-head-e9d4674>mvn clean package -Dmaven.test.
skip=true;
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING]
[WARNING]
 Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for org.mifos:mifos-
db:jar:1.8-SNAPSHOT

[WARNING]
 'build.plugins.plugin.(groupId:artifactId)' must be unique but found duplicate declara
tion of plugin org.liquibase:liquibase-maven-plugin @ line 132, column 21
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.(groupId:artifactId)' must be unique but found duplicate declara
tion of plugin org.liquibase:liquibase-maven-plugin @ line 149, column 21
[WARNING]

[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for org.mifos:mifos-
accounting:jar:1.8-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin is missin
g. @ line 29, column 21
[WARNING]
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of
your build.
[WARNING]

[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed
 projects.

[WARNING]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
 Reactor Build Order:
[INFO]
[INFO]
 Mifos - Parent

[INFO] Mifos - DB Management

[INFO] Mifos - Common

[INFO] Mifos - Domain Data Transfer Objects

[INFO] Mifos - Test Framework

[INFO] Mifos - Service Interfaces

[INFO] Mifos - User Interface

[INFO] Mifos - Accounting Integration

[INFO] Mifos - Questionnaire

[INFO] Mifos - Cashflow

[INFO] Mifos - Abstract Domain

[INFO] Mifos - Organization

[INFO] Mifos - Application Domain

[INFO] Mifos - Application

[INFO] Mifos - Acceptance Tests

[INFO]

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

[INFO] Building Mifos - Parent 1.8-SNAPSHOT

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

[INFO]

[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1:clean (default-clean) @ mifos-parent ---

[INFO]

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

[INFO] Building Mifos - DB Management 1.8-SNAPSHOT

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

[INFO]

[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1:clean (default-clean) @ mifos-db ---

[INFO] Deleting C:\mifos_src_code\mifos-head-2.1.6-0-gb6f7b86\mifos-head-e9d4674\db\target

[INFO]

[INFO] --- properties-maven-plugin:1.0-alpha-1:read-project-properties (default) @ mifos-db 
---

[WARNING] Ignoring missing properties file: C:\Users\Pavan.Kumar1\.mifos\local.properties

[INFO]

[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.3:resources (default-resources) @ mifos-db ---

[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.

[INFO] Copying 1 resource

[INFO]

[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) @ mifos-db ---

[INFO] No sources to compile

[INFO]

[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.3:testResources (default-testResources) @ mifos-db ---

[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.

[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\mifos_src_code\mifos-head-2.1.6-0-
gb6f7b86\mifos-h

ead-e9d4674\db\src\test\resources

[INFO]

[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ mifos-db ---

[INFO] No sources to compile

[INFO]

[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.10:test (default-test) @ mifos-db ---

[INFO] No tests to run.

[INFO] Surefire report directory: C:\mifos_src_code\mifos-head-2.1.6-0-gb6f7b86\mifos-head-
e9d46

74\db\target\surefire-reports



-------------------------------------------------------

 T E S T S

-------------------------------------------------------


Results :

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0


[INFO]

[INFO] --- liquibase-maven-plugin:2.0.0:updateSQL (update-sql) @ mifos-db ---

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

[INFO] Parsing Liquibase Properties File

[INFO]   File: target/classes/liquibase.properties

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

[INFO] Reactor Summary:

[INFO]

[INFO] Mifos - Parent .................................... SUCCESS [0.110s]

[INFO] Mifos - DB Management ............................. FAILURE [1.570s]

[INFO] Mifos - Common .................................... SKIPPED

[INFO] Mifos - Domain Data Transfer Objects .............. SKIPPED

[INFO] Mifos - Test Framework ............................ SKIPPED

[INFO] Mifos - Service Interfaces ........................ SKIPPED

[INFO] Mifos - User Interface ............................ SKIPPED

[INFO] Mifos - Accounting Integration .................... SKIPPED

[INFO] Mifos - Questionnaire ............................. SKIPPED

[INFO] Mifos - Cashflow .................................. SKIPPED

[INFO] Mifos - Abstract Domain ........................... SKIPPED

[INFO] Mifos - Organization .............................. SKIPPED

[INFO] Mifos - Application Domain ........................ SKIPPED

[INFO] Mifos - Application ............................... SKIPPED

[INFO] Mifos - Acceptance Tests .......................... SKIPPED

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

[INFO] BUILD FAILURE

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

[INFO] Total time: 2.080s

[INFO] Finished at: Mon May 21 10:57:16 IST 2012

[INFO] Final Memory: 7M/18M

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.liquibase:liquibase-maven-plugin:2.0.0:updateSQL 
(update-sql)

 on project mifos-db: Error setting up or running Liquibase: java.sql.SQLException: Access 
denie

d for user 'mifos'@'localhost' (using password: YES) -> [Help 1]

[ERROR]

[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.

[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

[ERROR]

[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the 
following

articles:

[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException

[ERROR]

[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command

[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :mifos-db

C:\mifos_src_code\mifos-head-2.1.6-0-gb6f7b86\mifos-head-e9d4674>'
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to start fixing your pom with the first lines:

```
[WARNING]
 'build.plugins.plugin.(groupId:artifactId)' must be unique but found duplicate declara
tion of plugin org.liquibase:liquibase-maven-plugin @ line 132, column 21
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.(groupId:artifactId)' must be unique but found duplicate declara
tion of plugin org.liquibase:liquibase-maven-plugin @ line 149, column 21
[WARNING]

[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for org.mifos:mifos-
accounting:jar:1.8-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin is missin
g. @ line 29, column 21
[WARNING]
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of
your build.
[WARNING]
```

After you fixed that i can see that based on this message:

```
 on project mifos-db: Error setting up or running Liquibase: java.sql.SQLException: Access 
denied for user 'mifos'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

That you are trying to access a database which does not allow a password in relationship with this user (Assuming MySQL ?). You have to fix the permissions for this user.

Comment: we fixed it.. this problem is created when we fail to authenticate with database so we changed C:\mifos_src_code\mifos-head-2.1.6\mifos-head\application\src\test\resources\org\mifos\config\resources\integrationDatabase file. its username n passwrd should be same same database username n password